# Is there a way to cache a angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript

what i would like to do is before my application is bootstrapped to ask if the app is cached if yes load the cached version else if there is no cached version bootstrapModule the app. Do you know if something like that is possible?

Comment: Perhaps using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: That's basically how a browser works by default, isn't it ? Or maybe I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's Webpack gives you this what you need. You can set configuration of webpack to adding hash to files your app. If something changes in the file, change hash.